# Двойная превосходная степень - можно ли сказать "самый лучший"?

Tags: перевод, значения

> Я начал молиться – не вслух, а так, про себя, будто разговаривая с непонятным мне существом, что смотрит за всеми нами и определяет жизнь каждого – от **самых лучших**, вроде Кати и моего отца, до свинарей, которых я ненавидел, но теперь, уже в кабине самолёта готовясь покинуть их, почти любил.

Как понимать сочетание **самый лучший**? Может

> ... from the **very best** ones, such as ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Грамота.ру [пишет](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9) о двойной превосходной степени: «Это допустимое сочетание для разговорной речи, в ситуации непринужденного общения. Но в образцовой литературной речи его лучше избегать».

И, конечно же, **the very best** – это правильная интерпретация выражения **самый лучший**.

Answer (score 2):

Как правило, такие конструкции тавтологичны, например, нельзя без иронии сказать "самый прекрасный" (прилагательное и без того выражает предельную степень). Но выражение "самый лучший" употребляется широко и не только в разговорной речи. В пользу его допустимости говорит и то, что в другом контексте "лучший" может означать сравнительную степень (лучше названного перед этим, напр. "есть лучший способ") или подразумевать относительность (лучший в ограниченном кругу сопоставляемого), а "самый лучший" такое понимание сразу исключает, добавляя ясности. Однако было бы бессмысленно рассуждать о том, что одно "прекрасно", но другое "прекраснее" его или что оно "самое прекрасное".

Answer (score 1):

Выскажу иную точку зрения. C английского very переводится как очень. В то время как самый это указательное местоимение. Произошло от сам.

```
Тот самый человек.
```

Тут же не имеется ввиду в значении очень. Имеется ввиду что это он сам и есть.

```
Тот самый день в который мы познакомились. Или тот самый лучший день...
```

Вдумайтесь в эти 2 предложения. Имеется ввиду что это он и есть. Или это он и есть лучший. Эта не превосходная степень а указание.

```
Тот очень хороший поступок. Тот самый хороший поступок.
```

Вдумайтесь.

Самый лучший переводится просто как The best.